# If I give changes in my api then how I can show that changes in my flutter ui without button?

Tags: flutter, api, rest, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

if changes in my api then how to use setstate in my flutter app Generally I used to updata my screen to back then come at that screen plz any body give answer to that question plz

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render the UI based on the response you can use a stream builder.. This builder rebuilds the UI when there is a change in the response

```
Stream<ResponseModel> responseStream() async {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    ResponseModel responseObj = getResponseFromAPI();
    yield responseObj;
  }
}


StreamBuilder(
          stream: responseStream(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Text(
              snapshot.data!,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: my api is not changing everytime it change only when i do at that part of operation over it

Comment: I didnt get you.

Comment: how to update profile pic in flutter like whatsapp